# Wordpress automatically deletes entire tables

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

Strange things have been happening on my website since yesterday.

It started with no menus being visible anymore. A look in wp-admin showed that there were no more menus. The problem: No more menus could be added. The error appeared:

```
The taxonomy term could not be inserted into the database.
```

When I then tried to insert a menu via the Customizer, nothing worked. The database tool showed me that several tables were no longer available, including postmeta and options.

Then I restored a backup from the day before. Everything was working again. The menus were back. After a few changes in Elementor I got a database error again. Whole tables were deleted again. I restored the backup and went to sleep.

When I woke up this morning, the page showed me a database error again. When I went to bed, everything ran smoothly.

This time the following tables were deleted:

```
gphn_posts: Table 'xxx.gphn_posts' doesn't exist
gphn_comments: Table 'xxx.gphn_comments' doesn't exist
```

I had not changed anything in the past days. Only a minor update of Rank Math was applied automatically and that already a few days ago.

Unfortunately, I have absolutely no idea where exactly to look for what could be triggering this problem.

Many greetings

Jonas

---

```
### wp-core ###

version: 5.9
site_language: de_DE
user_language: de_DE
timezone: +00:00
permalink: /blog/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/
https_status: true
multisite: false
user_registration: 0
blog_public: 1
default_comment_status: open
environment_type: production
user_count: 6
dotorg_communication: true

### wp-paths-sizes ###

wordpress_path: /pages/14/9f/d0015976/home/htdocs/sites/gluex
wordpress_size: 83,52 MB (87574947 bytes)
uploads_path: /pages/14/9f/d0015976/home/htdocs/sites/gluex/wp-content/uploads
uploads_size: 1,85 GB (1982448592 bytes)
themes_path: /pages/14/9f/d0015976/home/htdocs/sites/gluex/wp-content/themes
themes_size: 85,45 MB (89599359 bytes)
plugins_path: /pages/14/9f/d0015976/home/htdocs/sites/gluex/wp-content/plugins
plugins_size: 197,22 MB (206802038 bytes)
database_size: 244,16 MB (256016384 bytes)
total_size: 2,44 GB (2622441320 bytes)

### wp-dropins (1) ###

advanced-cache.php: true

### wp-active-theme ###

name: Astra Child (astra-child)
version: 1.0.0
author: Brainstorm Force
author_website: http://wpastra.com/about/
parent_theme: Astra (astra)
theme_features: core-block-patterns, astra_hooks, widgets-block-editor, align-wide, automatic-feed-links, title-tag, post-thumbnails, html5, post-formats, custom-logo, customize-selective-refresh-widgets, editor-style, woocommerce, rank-math-breadcrumbs, amp, editor-color-palette, wc-product-gallery-zoom, wc-product-gallery-lightbox, wc-product-gallery-slider, widgets, menus
theme_path: /pages/14/9f/d0015976/home/htdocs/sites/gluex/wp-content/themes/astra-child
auto_update: Deaktiviert

### wp-parent-theme ###

name: Astra (astra)
version: 3.7.7
author: Brainstorm Force
author_website: https://wpastra.com/about/?utm_source=theme_preview&utm_medium=author_link&utm_campaign=astra_theme
theme_path: /pages/14/9f/d0015976/home/htdocs/sites/gluex/wp-content/themes/astra
auto_update: Deaktiviert

### wp-themes-inactive (7) ###

Atmosphere Child: version: 1.5, author: Edge Themes, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
Atmosphere: version: 1.5, author: Edge Themes, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
Brynn: version: 1.3, author: Elated Themes, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
Twenty Nineteen: version: 2.2, author: WordPress-Team, Automatische Aktualisierungen aktiviert
Twenty Twenty: version: 1.9, author: WordPress-Team, Automatische Aktualisierungen aktiviert
Twenty Twenty-One: version: 1.5, author: WordPress-Team, Automatische Aktualisierungen aktiviert
Twenty Twenty-Two: version: 1.0, author: WordPress-Team, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert

### wp-mu-plugins (1) ###

installatron_hide_status_test.php: author: (undefined), version: (undefined)

### wp-plugins-active (24) ###

AnyWhere Elementor Pro (Premium): version: 2.22.2, author: WP Vibes, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
Astra Pro: version: 3.6.5, author: Brainstorm Force, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
Borlabs Cookie - Cookie Opt-in: version: 2.2.45, author: Benjamin A. Bornschein, Borlabs, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
Checkout Field Editor for WooCommerce (Pro): version: 3.1.8, author: ThemeHigh, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
Disable Google Fonts: version: 2.0, author: Milan Dinić, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
Elementor: version: 3.5.4, author: Elementor.com, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
Elementor Pro: version: 3.5.2, author: Elementor.com, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
Email Customizer for WooCommerce (Pro): version: 3.5.2, author: ThemeHigh, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
Imagify: version: 1.10, author: WP Media, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
Limit Login Attempts Reloaded: version: 2.23.2, author: Limit Login Attempts Reloaded, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
Loco Translate: version: 2.5.8, author: Tim Whitlock, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
LoftLoader Pro: version: 2.3.0, author: Loft.Ocean, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
Rank Math SEO: version: 1.0.81.1, author: Rank Math, Automatische Aktualisierungen aktiviert
Rank Math SEO PRO: version: 3.0.5, author: Rank Math, Automatische Aktualisierungen aktiviert
Smart Slider 3 Pro: version: 3.5.1.3, author: Nextend, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
The Plus Addons for Elementor: version: 5.0.5, author: POSIMYTH, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
The Plus Addons for Elementor - Pro: version: 5.0.8, author: POSIMYTH, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
WC Place Order Without Payment: version: 2.1, author: Nitin Prakash, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
WooCommerce: version: 6.1.1, author: Automattic, Automatische Aktualisierungen aktiviert
WooCommerce Customizer: version: 2.7.4, author: SkyVerge, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
Woocommerce Side Cart Premium: version: 3.1, author: XootiX, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
wp-Typography: version: 5.8.1, author: Peter Putzer, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
WP Downgrade | Specific Core Version: version: 1.2.2, author: Reisetiger, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert
WP Rocket: version: 3.10.7, author: WP Media, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert

### wp-plugins-inactive (1) ###

URL Shortify: version: 1.5.9, author: KaizenCoders, Automatische Aktualisierungen deaktiviert

### wp-media ###

image_editor: WP_Image_Editor_GD
imagick_module_version: Nicht verfügbar
imagemagick_version: Nicht verfügbar
imagick_version: Nicht verfügbar
file_uploads: File uploads is turned off
post_max_size: 513M
upload_max_filesize: 512M
max_effective_size: 512 MB
max_file_uploads: 20
gd_version: bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
gd_formats: GIF, JPEG, PNG, WebP, BMP, XPM
ghostscript_version: 9.25

### wp-server ###

server_architecture: Linux 5.4.147-r202109161543220000.x86_64 x86_64
httpd_software: Apache
php_version: 7.4.24 64bit
php_sapi: cgi-fcgi
max_input_variables: 1000
time_limit: 180
memory_limit: 512M
max_input_time: -1
upload_max_filesize: 512M
php_post_max_size: 513M
curl_version: 7.29.0 NSS/3.53.1
suhosin: false
imagick_availability: false
pretty_permalinks: true
htaccess_extra_rules: true

### wp-database ###

extension: mysqli
server_version: 5.5.68-MariaDB
client_version: mysqlnd 7.4.24
max_allowed_packet: 16777216
max_connections: 2550

### wp-constants ###

WP_HOME: undefined
WP_SITEURL: undefined
WP_CONTENT_DIR: /pages/14/9f/d0015976/home/htdocs/sites/gluex/wp-content
WP_PLUGIN_DIR: /pages/14/9f/d0015976/home/htdocs/sites/gluex/wp-content/plugins
WP_MEMORY_LIMIT: 512M
WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT: 512M
WP_DEBUG: false
WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY: true
WP_DEBUG_LOG: false
SCRIPT_DEBUG: false
WP_CACHE: true
CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS: undefined
COMPRESS_SCRIPTS: undefined
COMPRESS_CSS: undefined
WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE: Nicht definiert
DB_CHARSET: utf8
DB_COLLATE: undefined

### wp-filesystem ###

wordpress: writable
wp-content: writable
uploads: writable
plugins: writable
themes: writable
mu-plugins: writable
```

Answer (score 0):

After restoring the backup several times, whole tables keep disappearing after a few hours, for example:

```
gphn_comments: Table 'xxx.gphn_comments' doesn't exist
gphn_commentmeta: Table 'xxx.gphn_commentmeta' doesn't exist
gphn_wc_tax_rate_classes: Table 'xxx.gphn_wc_tax_rate_classes' doesn't exist
gphn_actionscheduler_actions: Table 'xxx.gphn_actionscheduler_actions' doesn't exist

gphn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta: Table 'xxx.gphn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta' doesn't exist
gphn_wpr_rucss_resources: Table 'xxx.gphn_wpr_rucss_resources' doesn't exist
```